Teenager or kid competition reality show with different themes
It started off with a bunch of different teams competing each other, then elimination starts until there was only one winner left. Each episode had a different theme. I remember parts of a few episodes:

A race to the set up camp
Working on a farm or ranch
Spy-like
Western-like
Possibly one had to do with rafting down a river.

I watched it within I believe the last 3 years... I think it was either a US or Canadian show. The filming locations all changed depending on the episode/challange. I just remembered that they where time-based challenges. I don't remember the host but I believe it was a male host.

Hi. What year and country was it from? Where\when did you watch it? Was it outdoors or in a studio? Do you remember anything else, about the overall theme of the show maybe or the hosts?

I watched it within I believe the last 3 years.... I think it was either a Us or Canadian show. The fliming locations all changed depending on the episode/challange. I just remembered that they where time base challenges. I don't remember the host but I believe it was a male host.

Finally found it. I was wrong with it being a male host. It's called: In Real Life. I must have watched a rerun of the first season. Thanks for the help though.

In Real Life (formerly known as In the Real World) is a Canadian reality show where eighteen young contestants aged 12–14 race across North America and compete in a series of real-life tasks, aimed to "discover the skills, strength, and stamina it takes to make it in real life."


Glad you found it. I elaborated a bit (which is always recommended). Don't forget to resolve the question by clicking on the check mark next to the answer and approving it.
